# Put MSMQ storage on D-drive

Tags: windows-server-2008, msmq

Our production server each have  two drives: C for OS and programs, D for our own platform, log files, backups, etc.

We extensively use MSMQ in our platform. I have noticed that the storage folder of MSMQ can be configured and that it's currently set to the default location on the C-drive.

Since we want all non-OS related things on the D drive (and space on the C drive is tight) I thought it would be a good idea to put the MSMQ storage also there.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But its not critical. The MSMQ storage take finite space (one or two GB) so it want explode your C drive.

Comment: You can move MSMQ for performance reasons to a different drive if the C: drive is usually busy with OS work. Also, always make sure MSMQ has quotas set on how much space is used for messages. In an error situation where messages just keep arriving without being processed, MSMQ can happily take up all your drive space and potentially bring the server down.